# Converting a JSON string to a VB DataTable (Newtonsoft.Json)

Tags: vb.net, json, serialization, datatable, json.net

My string looks like this

```
[{'Column1': 'c1r1', 'Column2': 'c2r1'},{'Column1': 'c1r2', 'Column2': 'c2r2'}]
```

I want to make it a datatable in Visual Basic with columns 'Column 1' and 'Column 2'.  I have tried

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(SaveTableJSON, GetType(System.Data.DataTable))
```

but it yields the error

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Additional text found in JSON string after finishing deserializing object.
```

This works just fine:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(SaveTableJSON)
```

Comment: What happens when you change it to GetType(System.Data.DataTable) instead of DataSet?

Comment: @NoAlias: Same thing.  That's actually what I was trying to do is make it a DataTable.  I updated the above.

Comment: What about CType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(SaveTableJSON), System.Data.DataTable) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `TryCast`
Try this function

```
 Public Function DeserializeDataTable(json As String) As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable
        dt = TryCast(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, (GetType(DataTable))), DataTable)
        Return dt
 End Function
```

Taken from internet :)

Comment: The error happened on DeserializeObject. Attempting to cast it to a DataTable after the deserialization error isn't going to help.